# Max number of items in a sharepoint list?

Tags: records-management

I currently have 28679 records in my sharepoint list, what is the max size with attachments a list can hold as well has max number of records in a list.

Thank you

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, a list can have up to 30 MILLION items. This is the hard-coded limit where it simply won't let you create even a single other item. However, there are other limits to consider:

- List view threshold: 5,000 items
- List view threshold for admins: 20,000 items
- Individual file size limit: 2 GB
- Total site limit for content database: 4 TB

A threshold is the "soft" limit. Once you reach that point, you'll start seeing slowness and other wonky problems. I've had a list that displayed 12,000 items, all at once, in a view. We always had a LOT of problems with that view, however, and it took so long to render that it was practically useless. Once I dialed it down to a more reasonable number under 5000, the problems went away and the list view became useful again.

To see all of the limits for SharePoint 2013, please see [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx). You can select other versions of SharePoint at the top of the article.

Long story short, you're well within parameters having only 30k items in the list. You'll just need to manage your views and compartmentalize the list as needed, so that individual users see only what they need and not all 30,000 at a time.

Comment: "Once you reach that point, you'll start seeing slowness", what kind if slowness? and what cause this slowness? thank you

Comment: @jobin - an individual view is designed to display no more than 5000 items (i.e. - on the screen at one time). Anything more than that and the view can take upwards of several minutes to render, or even just hang up altogether. At least, that's the behavior I've seen before. This is why views default to having Paging turned on so that they only show 100 items at a time. The more items a view shows, the longer it can take to render on the screen. People are impatient - we want it NOW, which means 30+ seconds to render a view will result in people complaining about SharePoint and blaming you.

Comment: A "Standard" or "HTML" view of a list with no sorting, grouping or totals will render all the items on the list, but the more items you want to see at once, and the more fields you want on the view, the longer it will take to render the page. The view will paginate at the "Item Limit" setting. I have successfully built views with only the ID column and one other column (eg Title) that showed 5,000 items at a time and rendered very fast.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 you have 30,000,000 per list.
But I recomend you to read **List and Library Items** section from [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Specially List view threshold and Security scope.