# Archiving a Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am currently using a custom list to log issues with equipment. The list has been utilized for 2019, and has around 1000 items. From what I understand, the max # of items in a custom list is 30,000.

In terms of managing data, is it better to archive these items and create a list for each year? Or just keep recording everything into a single custom list?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, I've just realised you probably mean 'archiving' I thought you meant 'achieving'

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of Q&As on this kind of question already.  Like [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136244/max-number-of-items-in-a-sharepoint-list#targetText=In%20SharePoint%202013%2C%20a%20list,List%20view%20threshold%3A%205%2C000%20items) for instance.  You might also like to browse through other questions tagged with the [large-list tag](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-lists) to gain an understanding of why it's not a good idea to have too many items in a list.  There's plenty of info out there on the list limits, [here is another](https://sharegate.com/blog/demystifying-the-sharepoint-list-thresholds).

Where I work for instance, we stick to the 5000 item limit.  [Other people](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/#targetText=The%20SharePoint%205000%20item%20limit,that%20returns%20all%20the%20results.) say different things though.

Regarding the year meta-data, there's no harm in using the same list for 2020 if you anticipate that new items will be generated at a similar rate.  If you were on 2,500 for 2019 then I would create a new list for 2020 in order to stay inside the 5000 item limit.  If you only have 1000 items per year, then your current list could safely be used for the next 4 years.